# What are these red flowers and green plants?

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs

I am in Pacific Northwest. It is end of July. These are blooming and look beautiful. I want to know what they are. Usually this time of the year, no more flowers.

[image]

I believe #1 is nasturtium? #3 is some kind of hosta?

Could you please help identify?

Comment: For next time: one question per flower. This time we have @bamboo which identified all, but often it is not the case, so we need discussion per flower (and approved answer per flowers). [BTW so you will receive and give more points).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 1 is Impatiens, most likely Impatiens walleriana, common name Busy LIzzie; No.2 is a Begonia, but I'm not sure which - the usual one for summer bedding is Begonia sempervirens, but it doesn't look exactly like that variety, though it may be. No. 3 is Solenostemon (previously called Coleus); these come in a range of variegated colours, and are grown primarily for their foliage.

These sorts of plants are what's known as 'summer bedding' in the UK - they are planted out at the end of May, and continue flowering non stop until the first frosts; this constant production of flowers is what makes them valuable for the summer garden, particularly for pots and containers. This link  https://www.jerseyplantsdirect.com/top-10-spring-and-summer-bedding-plants shows what the seller considers to be the top 10 bedding plants for summer - there are other bedding plants available which are also commonly used. In countries where the winters are not cold, some of these bedding plants may survive and flower again next year, or may continue flowering for months until they are exhausted.

You did not ask about the central plant with red flowers - that's another variety of Begonia.